# ¿Cómo un fragment puede interactuar con una actividad?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Estoy teniendo problemas al conectar un `fragment` con alguna actividad existente en mi app, lo que intento hacer es pasar un contenido de un `EditText` de la actividad a el `fragment` y viceversa.

Tengo las siguientes variables:

```
private TextView texto;
private ListView lista;
private EditText editText;
private Button boton;
```

Y en el constructor estoy poniendo esto:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment, container, false);

    texto= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.changeView);
    lista= (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    editText= (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.fragmentEditText);
    boton= (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.fragmentButton);

    boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mListener.botonComunicacion(editText.getText().toString());
        }
    });


    lista.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    return v;
}
```

pero de ahí tomar los datos se me dificultan, ¿me podrían dar alguna idea?

Comment: No entiendo lo que deseas, quieres pasar un valor de la Actividad al Fragmento?

Comment: @LostWoods84 nada como la documentación https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 4):

Para enviar datos desde una `Activity` a un `Fragment` puedes realizarlo mediante un `Bundle`.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("valorEditText", "From Activity");
MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment ();
//Agrega bundle como argumento al fragment.
myFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

En el método `onCreateView()` del Fragment recibes el valor:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //Aquí recibimos el valor.
    String valorEditTextdeFragment = getArguments().getString("valorEditText");    

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

En  tu `fragment` hata abajo tienes una `interface`, donde puedes poner todos los métodos que quieras por ejemplo:

```
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

puedes quitar la función que tiene y agregar otra, en tu caso quedaria asi:

```
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    void BotonComunicacion(String string);
}
```

Ya qué en tu botón estas mandando a llamar está función, solo asegurate que donde estés llamando tu `fragment` tengas implementado la función de `OnFragmentInteractionListener`:

```
public class actividad extends AppCompatActivity implements fragmment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
}
```

Una vez implementado te va a pedir que implementes tu función `BotonComunicacion` donde esa función es la que va a recibir la información cuando la mandas a llamar en tu `fragment` cuanto lo oprimen.

Answer (score 1):

Primero para tener la comunicación desde Actividad- fragment tendrías que crear un fragment y generar una función de sobre escribir el texto del fragment.

```
public void changeText(String string){
    texto.setText(string);
}
```

luego en la actividad donde quieras mandar esa informacion al fragment implementar su variable global

```
private fragment frag;
```

inicializarla

```
frag= (fragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
```

y tener una función de mandar la info o el Edit Text a fragment.

```
 public void sendInfo(View v){
    frag.changeText(editText.getText().toString());
}
```

Después, generar la interacción fragment-Actividad. Necesitas en la Interfaz del fragment `OnFragmentInteractionListener` modificarla y agregarle la funcion de comunicación,`void botonComunicacion(String string);

Al tener esto necesitas una funcion dentro de la actividad

```
 public void botonComunicacion(String string) {
    texto.setText(string);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

En el fragment puedes editarlo con una visualizacion de datos, en el fragment puedes poner

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Datos.class);
    intent.putExtra("nombre", arrayList.get(position).getNombre());
    startActivity(intent);
```

En la clase datos

```
private TextView nombre;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_visualizacion__datos);

    nombre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nombreDato);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Archivo de Properties

```
Properties properties;
File file = new File(getFilesDir(),FILENAME);
properties = new Properties();

try{
        if(file.exists()){
            FileInputStream fis=openFileInput(FILENAME);
            properties.loadFromXML(fis);
            fis.close();
            Toast.makeText(this,"PROPERTIES LOADED FROM FILE",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            saveStorage();
            Toast.makeText(this,"PROPERTIES FILE CREATED ON DEVICE",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


public void saveStorage() throws Exception {
    saveProperties();
    FileOutputStream fos=openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    properties.storeToXML(fos,null);
    fos.close();
}

public void saveProperties(){
    properties.setProperty("name", inputText.getText().toString());
}
  public void saveStorageButton(View v){
    try{
        saveStorage();
        Toast.makeText(this,"SAVE IN STORAGE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes explicarnos que hace este código? Así la respuesta sería válida para la pregunta, ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

La mejor forma es a trávez de un Listener

```
public interface TextListener {
    void sendText(String text);
}
```

y que lo implemente tu activity y tu fragment

desde la activity:

```
((TextListener) fragment).sendText("texto a enviar al fragment");
```

desde el fragment

```
((TextListener) getActivity()).sendText("texto a enviar al activity");
```

Comment: Cómo recibo el dato?

Comment: Crea la interface como la quieras llamar e implementala donde quieras recibir los datos, si quieres que el fragment envie datos al activity deberas implementarla en tu activity, una vez esto con esta linea "((TextListener) getActivity()).sendText("texto a enviar al activity");" puedes enviarle la informacion, de forma mas explicada lo que haces es obtener el activity y hacerle un cast a la interfaz que creaste y ya puedes llamar a los metodos que creaste en tu interfaz