# ¿Como guardar datos permanentemente en una pantalla (Fragment o Activity) en android aunque salga de esta?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, sharedpreferences

Espero me puedan apoyar con esta duda que no me deja avanzar con la app que estoy haciendo. Como puedo almacenar dos datos en la pantalla2 provenientes de la pantalla1  de forma permanente, de modo que cuando vaya a otra pantalla y regrese siga teniendo el mismo dato. 
Para esto he implementado este codigo. Pero los sigue perdiendo:

```
   final SharedPreferences prefe=this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("datos", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String idusu= getArguments()!=null ? getArguments().getString("idusu"):"SIN DATOS";
    String gasto= getArguments()!=null ? getArguments().getString("gasto"):"SIN DATOS";
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefe.edit();//SE crea un objeto de la clase Editor,obtengo la referencia del objeto de la clase SharedPreferences
    editor.putString("idusu", idusu);//Mediante el método putString almacenamos en idideta el valor del String cargado en el EditText
    editor.commit();//metodo commit de la clase editor hace que el dato quede almacenado en forma permanente en el archivo de preferencias para k caundo arranq la aplicación se recupere el último idideta ingresado
    //Toast.makeText(getContext(), nombre, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = prefe.edit();
    editor2.putString("gasto", gasto);
    editor2.commit();
    //Toast.makeText(getContext(), gasto2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    String nombre = prefe.getString("idusu", "valor nombre");
    String gasto2 = prefe.getString("gasto", "valor gasto2");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo que usas como método de almacenamiento `SharedPreferences`, el guardado de los valores es correcto pero te falta agregar el valor de "gasto":

```
final SharedPreferences prefe=this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("datos", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String idusu= getArguments()!=null ? getArguments().getString("idusu"):"SIN DATOS";
    String gasto= getArguments()!=null ? getArguments().getString("gasto"):"SIN DATOS";
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefe.edit();
    editor.putString("idusu", idusu);
    editor.putString("gasto", gasto);
    editor.commit();
```

**El problema por el cual no estas recuperando los valores almacenados previamente, es porque no estas definiendo de que preferencia los deseas obtener, el nombre de la preferencia lo definiste como "datos"**,

```
SharedPreferences prefe = getSharedpreferences("datos", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

por lo tanto para obtener los valores almacenados en cualquier parte de tu aplicación, se realizaría de esta forma:

```
SharedPreferences prefe = getSharedpreferences("datos", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String nombre = prefe.getString("idusu", "valor nombre");
String gasto2 = prefe.getString("gasto", "valor gasto2");
```

Comment: Gracias por contestar, ya lo hice asi como me comentas pero los sigo perdiendo, pues cuando regreso a la pantalla2 recarga:
          String idusu= getArguments()!=null ? getArguments().getString("idusu"):"SIN DATOS";

    String gasto= getArguments()!=null ? getArguments().getString("gasto"):"SIN DATOS";

entonces obtiene cada variable "SIN DATOS" y segun yo recarga  SharedPreferences prefe = getSharedpreferences("datos", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
donde al parecer renombra y ahora me imprime "valor nombre" y "valor gasto2"

Comment: Angelica, aquí es diferente, estos datos que recibes de esta forma:  String idusu= getArguments()!=null ? getArguments().getString("idusu"):"SIN DATOS";  se reciben cuando realizas un intent hacia una Activity https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36902/pasar-datos-entre-activities/36924#36924 pero en este caso lo estas haciendo a un Fragment deberías enviarlos de esta forma: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/28720/c%C3%B3mo-un-fragment-puede-interactuar-con-una-actividad/28729#28729 Agrega como tratas de enviar los datos mediante un Intent.

Comment: Cuando regresas a pantalla2 si guardaste los datos, puedes obtenerlos de la misma forma: SharedPreferences prefe = getSharedpreferences("datos", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String nombre = prefe.getString("idusu", "valor nombre");
String gasto2 = prefe.getString("gasto", "valor gasto2");

Comment: ya hice pruebas y si efectivamente los guarda, lo que pasa que esta relacionando el paso de parametros con el Sharedpreference. Muchisimas gracias